# Getting unique values in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table say :

```
id| AccID | Subject      | Date                       
1 | 103   | Open HOuse 1 | 11/24/2011 9:00:00 AM        
2 | 103   | Open HOuse 2 | 11/25/2011 10:00:00 AM       
3 |  72   | Open House 3 | 11/26/2011 1:10:28 AM        
4 |  82   | OPen House 4 | 11/27/2011 5:00:29 PM        
5 |  82   | OPen House 5 | 11/22/2011 5:00:29 PM
```

From the above table, i need all the unique values for the Accid. But say, if there are two or more columns with the same Accid, then i need the one which has the smaller date (among the columns which have the same Accid)

So, from the above table, the o/p should be :
1
3
5

Can any1 please help me in this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [MyTable] t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT AccID, MIN(Date) Date
    FROM [MyTable]
    GROUP BY AccID
) t2 ON t1.AccID = t2.AccID AND t1.Date = t2.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

More than just the AccID but...

```
WITH SEL
AS
(
    SELECT AccID, MIN(DATE)
      FROM table
     GROUP BY AccID
)
SELECT table.*
  FROM table
  JOIN SEL ON SEL.AccID = table.AccID
```

Comment: Shouldn't this join SEL on the Date and the AccID?  This looks like the CTE would have no effect.